# Which software do I need for taking the values from video

Tags: windows, video, video-editing, software-testing, microsoft-excel

which software can I use for taking the numbers from a video. For example I have an video with numbers 0, 250, 320, 0 , 0 ..... nothing else just numbers in the video. So I need these values to be put in txt or excel.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is 0, 0 in your list. How can the software decide that there are two 0s and not just one? Is there a blank screen in between? Just one number or many numbers at the same time?

Comment: Let say that I need to take the values from a scale. So when the weight is different than 0 and is stable(for example the value is not changed more than a second) this result to be pasted in excel for example.

Comment: Are the numbers clean and non-moving, with perfectly uniform background? Or are they hand-written numbers written on paper hold by someone who might shake a bit, recorded by a camera that sometimes rectifies its focus?

Comment: The numbers are clean and easily readable on not-changeable background. Digital not hand written. The camera is positioned only on the numbers without any movements.

Comment: Look up optical character recognition (OCR) software for video

Comment: Can you please recommend me a good software that includes OCR if possible to be free or atleast with trial(demo) version so if it does what I want I will buy it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Typically OCR is done on a single frame, so all of the solutions I know of involve some process that takes a single frame out of the video stream and attempts to image processing to clean it up before running OCR on it. I have not specifically tried either of these, but you could look at software such as [ConTEXTract](https://www.sri.com/engage/products-solutions/contextract-video-ocr) or a combination of open-source like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) along with [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).

I believe the best solution is likely to be one that is home grown. You could develop a custom all-in-one solution of your own using tools like those provided with [LEADTOOLS](https://www.leadtools.com/). With the Multimedia SDK, you could process all types of video and get still images using the video callback filter to clean up and pull data from using the Recognition Imaging SDK. With this, you could write out your own text/XLS file or have LEADTOOLS do this for you.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of the company that wrote the referenced SDK.